# Azure Data Factory - how to get total number of rows inserted

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline in Azure Data Factory that reads data from a source table and copies it into a sink table.  For that, I am using the 'Copy data' activity.  I want to fetch some metadata about the activity and insert it into a logging table.  In particular, I want to fetch the number of rows inserted into the sink table.  For that, I am using the 'Copy data' activity's output, i.e., `@activity('Copy data').output.rowsCopied`.  However, in doing so, I noticed that sometimes more than 1 "metadata" row is inserted into my logging table, with different values for rows copied / inserted.  One of the rows seems to be the correct total number of rows in the source table.  For example, if a source table has 10 rows, one row inserted into my logging table might have RowsInserted = 2, followed by another row with RowsInserted = 10.  Is there a way to resolve this?  That is, is it possible to insert only 1 row into my logging table?  I don't want the number of rows inserted by each batch.  I only want the total number of rows inserted for the given source table.

If it matters, I am loading several tables at once via a ForEach activity.  In my inner 'Copy data' activity, I have set 'Degree of copy parallelism' = 1 and my 'Write batch size' is empty (i.e., Azure Data Factory determines the optimal batch size).

Comment: can you add image of pipeline for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

> how to get total number of rows inserted

You can find copied rows in activity output by using below expression:

```
@activity('copyActivity').output.rowsCopied
```

Write batch size and Degree of copy parallelism Doesn't affect it is only for the performance purpose.

To insert no of rows inserted/copied use the stored procedure to insert the values and call this stored procedure using stored procedure activity.

you can check this [document](https://www.techbrothersit.com/2022/01/azure-data-factory-check-row-count-of.html) to store the No. of copied rows SQL table using stored procedure

> I am loading several tables at once via a ForEach activity.

The issue is causing because may be if you are loading several tables into single sink using copy activity it will store the rows copied values for each iteration for single sink also.